# How to have a successful compiled of Puppeteer's Assets using laravel-mix. Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, puppeteer, laravel-mix

Good afternoon everybody,

I have been stuck in this issue for a long time today and would like some help; I cannot run Puppeteer using laravel-mix to compile everything.
Now, I can run `npm install puppeteer` and run my screenshot script normally when I don't have to compile my js file through laravel-mix.

Anyway, with the simple steps to reproduce my current bug:
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run production`
The last command throws a lot of warnings:

```
These dependencies were not found: 
* child_process in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js, ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Launcher.js
* fs in ./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js, ./node_modules/extract- zip/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js and 20 others
* net in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js
* readline in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js, ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Launcher.js
* tls in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs net readline tls

These relative modules were not found:

* ./types/other in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/mime/index.js
* ./types/standard in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/mime/index.js
```

So naturally, I run `npm install --save child_process fs net readline tls` to install these dependencies and then run `npm run production` once again.
  The same errors pop-up. So I do some [research](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2142) and learn that `child_processes` is part of node already and I added these 3 lines to my `webpack.mix.js` file. According to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#custom-webpack-configuration), you can merge webpack configurations this way

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  target: 'node',
});
```

That got rid of most error messages, great!

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ./types/other in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/mime/index.js
* ./types/standard in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/mime/index.js
```

According to most issues [[1]](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2754) [[2]](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6459) [[3]](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/550) on Github, there needs to be support to `.json` file extensions. So I appended to my previous added code in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
  },
});
```

So let's try `npm run production` once more, and it compiles! Except it doesn't work and we get these warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
13:9-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/bufferutil/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
20:15-54 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/bufferutil/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js
255:18-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js
26:25-81 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Launcher.js
26:25-81 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/BrowserFetcher.js
333:18-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/BrowserFetcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/lib/Puppeteer.js
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/index.js
 @ ./headless/screenshot.js
 @ multi ./headless/screenshot.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

I did some more [research](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196) on these warnings and nothing really can be resolved on my end. But the final bug I am stuck on when running my screenshot script is:

```
Error Output:
================
/home/project-path/public/js/screenshot.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { !function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var i=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,n),i.l=!0,i.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}({"+HRN":function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n("X3l8").Buffer;e.exports=function(){function e(){!function(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,e),this.head=null,this.tail=null,this.length=0}return e.prototype.push=function(e){var t={data:e,next:null};this.length>0?this.tail.next=t:this.head=t,this.tail=t,++this.length},e.prototype.unshift=function(e){var t={data:e,next:thi

Error: Cannot find module "."
```

Here is the script in hand:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    //parse arguments
    var args = process.argv;
    var indexes = [2, 3, 4];
    var arg_index = {};
    arg_index[2] = 'URL';
    arg_index[3] = 'File Path';
    arg_index[4] = 'Display';
    indexes.forEach(function(index){
        if(typeof args[index] == 'undefined'){
            var parameter = arg_index[index];
            console.log('Missing Parameter: ' + parameter);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });
    var url = args[2];
    var file_path = args[3];
    var display = args[4];
    var window_width = 1920;
    var window_height = 1080;
    if(display == 'mobile'){
        var window_width = 375;
        var window_height = 667;
    }

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: window_width, height: window_height});
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.waitFor(1500);
    await page.screenshot({path: file_path, type: 'png', fullPage: true});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Any ideas?
edit:
Some extra information for the curious.
Laravel: 5.5.40
Node: v8.11.3
NPM: 5.6.0
Laravel-Mix: 1.7.2
Puppeteer: 1.6.0

Comment: Probably due to the immediately invoked function and not exporting anything from the file. How are you importing/requiring the script?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I'm using a route to call a command using Symphony's [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). In the [reference docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for puppeteer they ask to run scripts using ```node```. So I run ```node path/to/screenshot.js url file_path display```.   The script parses through these extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to bundle the puppeteer or node_modules from Webpack.

You can give it a shot by this plugin to easily ignore all node_modules: [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#description)